# How do I find out which function is called when using R generics?

Tags: r, generics, plot

If I load a package like `raster`, then `?plot` gets me two methods in the help file (the `base` plotting and a plotting function from the `raster` package).

When I have an R object, how do I know which of the plotting functions is triggered?

Specifically, I have a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` and I am looking for documentation on how to add a legend etc., but I don't know where to start looking for the function.

Comment: You should use `spplot` function on your `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the methods available

```
> methods(plot)
 [1] plot,ANY,ANY-method                   
 [2] plot,Extent,missing-method            
 [3] plot,Raster,ANY-method                
 [4] plot,Raster,Raster-method             
 [5] plot,Spatial,missing-method           
 [6] plot,SpatialGrid,missing-method       
 [7] plot,SpatialLines,missing-method      
 [8] plot,SpatialMultiPoints,missing-method
 [9] plot,SpatialPixels,missing-method     
[10] plot,SpatialPoints,missing-method     
[11] plot,SpatialPolygons,missing-method   
[12] plot,VectorLayer,ANY-method           
[13] plot.acf*           
...
```

Note the way S4 methods are presented in the `methods()` function. Look up the corresponding help page with

```
?"plot,SpatialPolygons,missing-method"
```

If the method isn't obvious try `selectMethod()` and look at the 'defined' entry in the signatures table:

```
> selectMethod("plot", c("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", "missing"))
Method Definition:

function (x, y, ...) 
plot.SpatialPolygons(x, ...)
<environment: namespace:sp>

Signatures:
        x                          y        
target  "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" "missing"
defined "SpatialPolygons"          "missing"
```